# Create RTSP for video file

Tags: linux, node.js, video

I have video sharing website.Where I am using

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

But its make my website slow .Also the user cannot enjoy the video on slow net.So I want to create `RSTP` TO disply video using stream . 
I am using NodeJS as frontend .Do you have any idea how can I use ?

Comment: RSTP is a protocol that's used to link to a video streaming back end.  It's kind of like a media server that serves up just video.  Similar to how an http server serves up html and js.  You would need to deploy a media server that can serve up RSTP protocol and ( probably ) transcode video.  Look at ffmpeg and read a lot before proceeding.  You are treading into deep waters.

Comment: ```RTSP``` (not RSTP, BTW) will not help you with slow link speeds.  If your connection is slow, switching to a streaming solution will still be slow.

There will be changes in the flow of the information, but it's not going to be a monumental thing...  You could probably do as much, more easily, by hosting the videos on a CDN.